# Is it still possible to purchase a license for Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server from Apple?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac-appstore, apple-store, osx-server

[Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leopard Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Server#Mac_OS_X_Server_10.6_.28Snow_Leopard_Server.29) is no longer for sale at the Apple Store website. Mac OS X Server software licenses were sold as a separate full operating system from Apple until 10.7 Lion, though few realized that the client versions of Mac OS X could always be converted into the Server version product of the Mac OS X System Software (except for [Rhapsody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Server#Mac_OS_X_Server_1.0_.28Rhapsody.29)) simply by purchasing a license and downloading and installing the OS X Server pkg over the client software, even before the Mac App Store existed, just as it is now the only way to get OS X Server for Lion and subsequent versions of OS X Server.

1. If I purchase a license for and copy of [OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) from the Apple Store, and install this on a new Mac Mini, and I update the System to [10.6.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1399), can I then, through the Mac App Store, purchase a license for and a download a copy of the pkg installer for Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leopard Server from the Mac App Store (which first appears in 10.6.7)?
2. Though there may not be the option through the Apple Store web site, in purchasing new hardware today from Apple, if you request it, Apple will sell you a license for and a copy of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard *and install it for you on the hardware you purchased*. Will they sell a license for Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leopard Server with it and install it for you, if you request it?

---

While I am aware that you can [still download](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1403) and install [Server Admin Tools 10.6.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3931), even on the client versions of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, currently, my only Intel Mac is running a highly customized version of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, and I am unable to check for myself (or I would) if the Mac OS X 10.6 Server Snow Leopard Server package is available for sale and download or not through the Mac App Store. Can a kind and very shrewd soul still running Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard fire up their Mac App Store for me and see if they can even get to the [OS X Server software package](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id7145479290) for sale on the Mac App Store, and at least comment if not answer, regarding whether they believe or know they can actually purchase, download and install it, converting their Snow Leopard System Software into a full retail version of Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leopard Server? Thank you so very very much!

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to buy five year old software, of which I don't believe to be updated often in the future?

Comment: @MaxRied -a mature and stable OS is a mature and stable OS. Apple _is still supporting SL for security updates_, but no new features expected. Its OK. Snow Server IS A FAR BETTER SERVER product than subsequent OS X Server editions for a number of reasons, admin tools much more powerful, has the Rosetta emulation layer, it uses Samba for SMB, has "Save As," and is far more customizable, makes fewer decisions than Lion and subsequent version, leaving control to the admin. [compare](http://tinyurl.com/6pttsvc). New is not always best. SL is for the real Pros, Lion, ML, Mavericks is for n00bz. ;-)

Comment: @MaxReid - FWIW, Jag Server, Panther Server, Tiger Server, and _especially_ Leopard Server are also very good editions, very powerful and stable. If I could get a license for Leopard Server I would, it is better than Lion, ML or Mavericks server, even has things it can do that Snow Leopard can not, like manage OS9, OS8, OS7 machines, and it can RUN OS9 in Classic Mode, share it via Remote Desktop. Apple is rapidly moving towards a "one size fits all" product… but the result will be "one size fits no one," and they will lose all server market business. I hope they come to their senses soon!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snow Leopard Server was never made available via the App Store, it was only ever sold in the form of a separate OS install (or bundled with a server computer). While you cannot buy SL Server from store.apple.com, I believe you *can* buy it over the phone (1-800-MY-APPLE) (at least, you could last year -- I did) for $19.99 (maybe plus shipping, I don't remember). Note that you're purchasing the physical install DVD, not just a license code.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The client version is [$19.99](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) and still available from the Apple Store, and the current version of the OS X Server v3.0 package for Mavericks is $19.99. Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leoapard Server _was_ like $499 for the 10-client version. If they reduced that to $19.99 I'd be ecstatic. I guess I'll call Apple tomorrow. And while I wasn't sure if it was ever available from the Mac App Store, as I state in my question, it was once available for download as an install package over client.

Comment: Yep. When phoning in, you have to be sure they understand you want the server version (not plain Snow Leopard); the price is the same. Only real difference is that plain Snow Leopard is available from the online store as well as via phone order, but SL Server is phone-order only.

Comment: @GordonDavisson is correct, I need a copy of Snow Leopard Server to be able to run in a VM. It was $19.99 ordered by phone.

Comment: BTW, I originally learned it was available from [the virtualization discussion on Macintouch.com](http://www.macintouch.com/readerreports/virtualization/topic4300.html#d07mar2013). SL Server is useful because the license allows virtualization (on Apple hardware), and it includes Rosetta to run old PowerPC software. If you want to use PowerPC apps on a modern Mac, it's pretty much your only choice (even if you don't care at all about the server capabilities).

Comment: I just got off the phone with Apple, and I am the proud new owner of 2 brand spankin' new licenses and copies of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server - Unlimited License, and 1 license and copy of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard client for a grand total of $63.87. I thank you my good man, @GordonDavisson, and I thank you, again! [This question is answered](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGcTcDcrx9s).

Comment: As an update, I was just able to order Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server by phone from Apple. The rep was amazed it was still for sale! Oct. 8, 2014.

Comment: a 15 minute call to apple and my copy of ox 10.6 server will ship in a few weeks, thanks to your comments got the right track as 10/12/14 $25, $19.99 plus shipping

Comment: For what it's worth, the "part number" is MC588Z/A . I just called Apple to order and the agent didn't find it by name, but this number worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that you can still buy Snow Leopard Server with an unlimited client license over the phone.  I just did so today (2014-12-04) in Australia for a total cost including delivery of AUD24.95, about USD21.  The sales person that I spoke was knowledgable and knew exactly what is was without me having to quote the part number.  I think that he may have had a scripted question and asked me whether I was using it in a virtual environment such as "Parallels" or on physical hardware.

**EDIT:** I just got off the phone today (2015-01-27) with Apple, and Apple Tech Support (USA), and they are no longer shipping Snow Leopard Server.  Suggested I look for a copy on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you with an Apple Mac Developer program membership, you can download a copy of Snow Leopard Server from the developer download center.

The downloaded version doesn't include a serial key however.

Comment: The downloaded version did include a serial number, and still does, however it expired December 31st of 2015.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts (January to February 2017), no Apple representative has claimed to be able to offer me any part number that I've seen claimed to work to buy new Snow Leopard.

[Snow Leopard Server is available for $189 on Amazon; 9 are in stock.](http://amzn.to/2l1ZNib)