# Snow Lopard with Yosemite host

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, virtualization

I have an old app I need to run. How can i run SL as guest with Yosemite as host with MacBook Air 2011 and vbox? I own SL retail and the MacBook Air is apple, there shouldn't be any legal issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed to run a Server version of Snow Leopard in a virtual machine.

From Lion you are allowed to run the same guest OS X as the running host OS X - and you are allowed to install a client version of the OS.

Comment: Note that the server version of Snow Leopard appears to still be available if you order by phone (at 1-800-MY-APPLE or local equivalent), part #MC588Z/A, $19.99 + shipping. See [this previous question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131145/is-it-still-possible-to-purchase-a-license-for-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-server).