# installing Snow Leopard in VirtualBox, but it won't complete the installation

Tags: snow-leopard, install, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm getting ready to upgrade my MacBook Pro from Snow Leopard to El Capitan, but I want to be able to keep running MT-Newswatcher, so I want to run SL in VirtualBox. I followed the directions at this site

http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/02/snow-leopard-virtualbox.html

and everything seemed to be going well through step 4. After it went through the SL Installer, I clicked on Restart. But then it shows a screen saying I need to restart again. I can't seem to get past this.

[image]

I'm using the retail Snow Leopard disk I bought years ago. Could this be because I'm installing regular Snow Leopard and not Snow Leopard Server?

I also tried the additional steps here:

https://stephenmonro.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/running-mac-os-snow-leopard-in-virtual-box-on-a-mac-not-a-hackintosh/

specifically the additional lines in ~/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml

```
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs" value=" "/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal2/SmcDeviceKey" value="ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"/>
```

Now I don't get that screen, but when it tries to boot I get

[image]

Could the problem be due to the version of VirtualBox? I was hoping to get the VM working before I upgraded my Mac, and the latest version of VB that runs on Snow Leopard is 4.2. When you're creating the VM, OS X Snow Leopard isn't listed in the Version menu, as I see in most of the web sites that show how to do this. So maybe I need to switch to El Capitan first, install VB 5.0, and install it again.

Comment: Mac OS X Snow Leopard client version is not allowed to be virtualized by its SLA.

Comment: I know about that, and I'm willing to take the risk that Apple's lawyers come after me.

Comment: @user3439894 I've read that I can purchase Snow Leopard Server from Apple. But when I search for it on the Apple website, I just find [this](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard?fnode=1ecb84eba546897e22a99f66a7fe8883efd8600ceec42c3745bda2c579b710f2777081bb001e40f476818062e0ab7489576faf3ec5fef1685a94555297142f6b78551bec69110de5bcf09b90e974a41012188c7012e3bf70986bea5de9f96256) which seems to be the same Snow Leopard that I already have. Do I have to go to eBay to find it?

Comment: aha, just read [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131145/is-it-still-possible-to-purchase-a-license-for-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-server) that SL Server can only be purchased over the phone, not online.

Comment: I just got off the phone with Apple and you want to call 866-752-7753 and the Part # is MC588Z/A and it's MAC OS X 10.6.3 SLSVR UNLCL SING LIC-INT and if they're having trouble finding it tell them it's under tech solutions.

Comment: Sigh, I read in that other thread that it hasn't been available since Jan 2015, so I just ordered one on eBay.

Comment: @user3439894 I tried calling that number, it wanted me to enter an access number. Earlier tonight I tried calling 800-MY-APPLE, and gave up waiting on hold after about 10 minutes. I'll stick with my eBay order; it's a little more expensive, but it will arrive in a few days, and I suspect it will be slower from Apple.

Comment: It's absolutely still available from Apple although it will not show up in the computer on the regular retail side when calling the normal 800 # and why my rep said to tell you to mention it's under tech solutions and gave me that phone number, although that's not the number I called.  BTW When I ordered my copy from Apple, several years ago now, I received it in three days.  With tax and shipping it was ~$25.